# First GLWindow in first NewtCanvasAWT doesn't get .repaint(), when there are other windows

Tags: java, swing, awt, jogl

I have two [JOGL](https://jogamp.org/jogl/) native `GLWindow`s wrapped in `NewtCanvasAWT`.

These canvases are added to `JInternalFrame`s each. `JInternalFrame`s are added to `JDesktopPane` which is added to a `JFrame`.

I don't have an `Animator` running because `.display()` is called manually, when scene changes.

---

This setup works as expected apart from one thing:

- when the second `JInternalFrame` (order of creation) moves over the first, the first is not repainted, what is quite unexpected,
- when the first moves over the second, the second *is* repainted, as expected.
- If I add more frames, only the last one behaves as expected.

The `JInternalFrames` are identical (the same class).

The first `GLWindow` doesn't receive `WindowUpdateEvent` in `WindowListener.windowRepaint()`. The second one does.

Here's the stack trace of my `GLEventListener.display(GLAutoDrawable drawable)` from the *working* `JInternalFrame`:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: test
    at edu.agh.tunev.ui.opengl.Scene.display(Scene.java:42)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:373)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:358)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawableBase$2.run(GLAutoDrawableBase.java:280)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:655)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:594)
    at com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow.display(GLWindow.java:543)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawableBase.defaultWindowRepaintOp(GLAutoDrawableBase.java:99)
    at com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow.access$000(GLWindow.java:94)
    at com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow$1.windowRepaint(GLWindow.java:107)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.consumeWindowEvent(WindowImpl.java:2392)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.consumeEvent(WindowImpl.java:1943)
    at jogamp.newt.DisplayImpl.dispatchMessage(DisplayImpl.java:388)
    at jogamp.newt.DisplayImpl.dispatchMessages(DisplayImpl.java:436)
    at jogamp.newt.DisplayImpl$DispatchMessagesRunnable.run(DisplayImpl.java:371)
    at jogamp.newt.DefaultEDTUtil$EventDispatchThread.run(DefaultEDTUtil.java:293)
```

This should also happen with the *first* frame. Why doesn't it?

---

All this does not happen when using `GLJPanel` or `GLCanvas`. However, I do not want to use AWT thread for rendering and these `GLAutoDrawable`s use it. `NEWT` native windowing toolkit uses another thread.

Comment: You may be [*Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Comment: According to the article, heavy- and lightweight components can be safely mixed now.

Comment: Except for "a few situations that might affect your code," which you should verify.

Comment: @trashgod, you're right, I'm sorry. :) Confirmed by JOGL dev: [bug report](https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=726).

Comment: +1 for bug report; you can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188) if you have a workaround; if not, you might look for a suitable listener in which to call `revalidate()`.

Comment: @trashgod, that's what I did. Will answer in minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. This is a [bug in JOGL](https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=726).

I ended up adding a listener to `JDesktopPane`, that listens for `JInternalFrame` adds. If added frame contains `GLWindow`, it remembers a reference to it in a `List`. It also adds a shared `ComponentListener` to *every* `JInternalFrame`. Upon `componentHidden`/`componentMoved`/`componentResized`/`componentShown` events, all previously remembered `GLWindow`s are refreshed.

**Edit**: refreshing is implemented by invoking `.display()` method on `GLWindow` (inherited from `GLAutoDrawable`).

Comment: Can you elaborate on "refresh"? `validate()`? `repaint()`?

Comment: Thanks! Questions related to this arise often enough that it's good to have a first-hand account to cite.